# Creating ipa on new mac without exporting developer profile from old mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have to create an ipa for the ad-hoc distribution. The problem is, I `don't have the access to the mac on which first time developer profile is created and signed by the keychain password`, so can't export the `.developerprofile` file to code signIn on my new mac. I do know the keychain password. Now my question is, how can I create the ipa or generate a `new .developerprofile`. I searched alot but didn't get any related info. Everywhere creating new provision profile is listed. I am using Xcode 8

Comment: do you have apple dev login credentials?

Comment: login the account in xcode, once it prompt out the error message, choose "fix it"

Comment: It says, your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate.

Comment: Just make, `Provision Profile` and `Code Sign In Identity` automatic and Build, it will create ipa.

Comment: Its done already, but giving above error

Answer (score -1):

You can download the developer profile from developer.apple.com domain. Look at there. It is in the developer certificate or distribution certificate.